# How to test Number for zero java

Tags: java, numbers, equality

I can't seem to figure out how to test a number to see if it's zero. Couldn't someone please tell me what I'm missing.

```
getMin = Number.class
getMax = Number.class
```

Test

```
Number value = mvFacet.getMin() > 0 ? mvFacet.getMin() : mvFacet.getMax();
System.out.println(value.toString());
```

Comment: I can't figure out what any of your code has to do with testing a number for zero.  Are you asking how to test if a Number is equal to zero?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far? And why are `getMin` and `getMax` instances of Class?

Comment: Yes, I have an object returning a number, if min is equal to zero I need to get max. I've tried casting it to an Integer and I have yet to have any success.

Comment: doesn't `if(value == 0)` check if it is zero or not?

Comment: Doesn't work, incomparable types, Number and int. I'm really confused.

Comment: Try using the Number class's [intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue%28%29) method instead of just casting. Then you can just `== 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Number num;
...
if(num.intValue() == 0) {
    // num is 0 so do something here
}
```

Other methods available on Number are:

```
byteValue()
doubleValue()
floatValue()
longValue()
shortValue()
```

Select whichever method makes the most sense for the values you are using.

Comment: but what if num for example is a double - what num.intValue() returns then?

Comment: The Java documentation is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue-- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#intValue--

Answer (score 5):

To add to [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25882179/2766908), if you're going to use `num.doubleValue()` then don't use `==` since it doesn't handle edge cases like when the double value is `NaN` or `Infinity`. Please use `Double.compare(num.doubleValue(), 0.0);`.

Comment: I like this approach better than the accepted answer, where using `intValue()` would treat `0.1` as zero.